# I need to submit a form and proceed to next page in Mechanize in Python, but there are no submit Buttons

Tags: python, html, mechanize

I am trying to submit a form on a page which has no actual submit button. A snippet of the code is below. I don't want to use Selenium and want it to be purely mechanize.

I know that the form is being filled in okay though.

If i try and put a

```
br.form.submit()
```

I get

```
AttributeError: class HTMLForm has no attribute 'submit'
```

Below is the code:

HTML
These are the only buttons on the page

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Cancel" onclick="submitForm('Cancel')" />
<input type="button" name="button" value="Refresh" onclick="submitForm('Refresh')" />
<input type="button" name="button" value="Next" onclick="submitForm('Next')" />
```

This is the form code (anonymised):

```
<form name="Theformname" method="post" action="/theactionurl">
```

Any help would be appriciated

Image of what the page is arranged: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2v92cYx98uYc1ZoZnp0NzJ6R3M/view?usp=sharing

**UPDATE** **2014-11-06**

This is the underlying code for the JS function thats called

```
function submitForm(submitValue) {
    document.Theformname.action.value = submitValue;

    document.disabled="true";
    document.Theformname.submit();
  }
```

Comment: The `onclick` means it's using javascript. Without seeing the actual page it's hard to say if you can work around this, but chances are you will need to enable javascript in mechanize for this to work.

Comment: I thought that Mechanize didn't have JavaScript support, ive added mockup of what the page looks like

Comment: Show `submitForm()` js function implementation. Thanks.

Comment: @VishalJethwa: it seems that all javascript support has been removed from Mechanize. Old versions had some limited support for V8 IIRC. Perhaps you can fake the results by manually adding a submit button yourself. Beyond that I'm not really sure